# Adjust an AWK sub statement to replace values between two strings for any combination of characters

Tags: bash, awk

Test Data

```
 Test Data 1: <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">1</stringProp>
 Test Data 2: <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">$$fred7723!</stringProp>
```

Desired Change:

```
Test Data 1: <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">99</stringProp>
Test Data 2: <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">99</stringProp>
```

This following code successfully updates Test Data 1. 
How can I adjust the code to get the desired output for Test Data 2 please?

In Test Data 2 the string being replaced can be any combination of numbers, letters, special characters and/ or characters.

```
overrides_duration=99
overRides=$(awk -v newValue="$overrides_duration" '$0 ~ /stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"/ {a=$0; sub(/<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">[0-9]+/,"<stringProp name=\"ThreadGroup.duration\">"newValue,a); print a; next;}{}1' "${testDataLocation}");
```

Comment: Can the string in Test Data 2 include a `<`, e.g. inside quotes or escaped or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use a similar but simpler `awk`

```
$ awk -v newvalue=99 -v k='stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">' \
        'sub(k "[^<]*<",k newvalue "<")' file

 Test Data 1: <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">99</stringProp>
 Test Data 2: <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">99</stringProp>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple sed do handle this:

```
sed 's/>[^<]*/>99/' file

Test Data 1: <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">99</stringProp>
Test Data 2: <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">99</stringProp>
```